# Create JSON from mysqli query based on primary key

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am probably phrasing this poorly, but I am pulling data from a database and I want to turn it into a JSON file.

My problem is I want to save it into JSON with this structure:

```
{
    "PRIMARYKEY": { 
        "COLUMN1":"VALUE1",
        "COLUMN2":"VALUE2"
    }
}
```

And it's tripping me up. I'm getting a message about not being able to use object of type mysqli_result as an array, but I am using fetch_assoc(). How do I convert this mysqli_result to a more useable format and get it into the JSON format I need? I want it in this JSON format because it seems like the best way to handle pulling information and searching the JSON file.

Comment: did you try `json_encode`?

Comment: The JSON structure you described is not valid JSON. Regarding your question, you must iterate over mysql result and populate a new php array with the fields you need. Then you use json_encode to convert array to json encoded string. Then you can write this string to a file or whatever you need.

Comment: Sorry, edited the JSON to be valid. I just kind of put that together real quick as an example. My problem is I can't populate my PHP array as it is complaining that I can't do that with a mysqli result.

Comment: Can you post the code where you fetch your data?

Comment: Actually I started over and I"m not getting the mysqli error anymore. I'm not sure what I did differen.t I think I was calling the data incorrectly. My main problem now is trying to structure the array and such like the sample JSON I posted. I'm trying to figure out the proper way to iterate through and save each key value pair to a subarray of each Primary Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also figured out my own question I foreached my query and did the following:

```
$JSONVARIABLE[$row["PrimaryKey"]] = array(
'Column1' => $row['Column1'], 
'Column2' => $spell['Column2']
);
```

I don't know why this gave me so much trouble, it was really obvious in the end. Still new at this I guess. Hopefully this will help someone else later on. Creates the JSON I need in the proper format. Thanks for the help everyone!